# Over-zealous RedirectMatch in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just converted a website that had thousands of bad links, and I have been cleaning up tens of thousands of indexing errors, some with redirect 301s and some with RedirectMatch. However, I am getting one error that puzzles me.

Either of these two lines of code in the .htaccess file

```
RedirectMatch 301 /faqs(.*) http://www.belleviewanimalclinic.com/pet-care-faqs/
RedirectMatch 301 /faq(.*) http://www.belleviewanimalclinic.com/pet-care-faqs/
```

cause this page

`http://www.belleviewanimalclinic.com/denver-veterinarian-articles/faqs-about-pet-dentistry/`

to be redirected here

`http://www.belleviewanimalclinic.com/pet-care-faqs/`

There are lots of old URLs that started with /faqXXXXXX that need to be redirected to the new FAQ page. However, I don't want this to apply to the article above.

Is there a way I can rewrite the RedirectMatch rules so that only URLs that start with /faq are redirected, rather than somewhere in the middle of the request URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a caret to match the start of a path:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/faqs?(.*) http://www.belleviewanimalclinic.com/pet-care-faqs/
```

I merged the two lines into one by making the "s" optional (by following it with a "?"). The caret should make it so the path has to begin with faq, not just include it.

*Note: I initially removed the beginning slash since match strings generally start after the beginning slash, however I'm more used to RewriteRules than RedirectMatches and I believe the behavior may be different.*